# Unexpected error while trying to create a SSID

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, ssid

I'm trying to add an hidden SSID to my computer, but when I add the network I get an error:

> Unexpected error

Tried to uninstall, install it back, then update but still the same problem.

Comment: This sounds like the network is rejecting your attempt to connect to it.

Comment: @Ramhound I also thought that but if the problem was with only that SSID i would be able to create a different one (with another name), right?

Comment: I am thinking more up the lines of your trying to connected to SSID A with configuration A but the actual configuration is B.

Comment: OK but i tryied also to create SSID C and returns the same error

Comment: Which uses the same configuration as SSID A.  I am trying to hint that you should verify the encryption option you selected match the security options on the access point side of things is the same as the what you selected on the pc side of things.

Comment: the SSID is not the problem as far I know, i have more than 100 hosts connected to it

Comment: Is there an error code presented with the message, or possibly in an error event visible in the Event Viewer (Start -> Run 'eventvwr.msc', OK)? Windows "unexpected error" messages often cover a lot of possibilities, and knowing which error code (if any) is reported along with that rather useless message is frequently very helpful in finding a resolution.

Comment: No, there is no error code, i think it was an update that was conflicting with wireless drivers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is mostly caused by moving an account from one computer to another and also moving symantec settings to the new computer (using easy transfer).
To solve it open regedit,  go to  `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\RasMan\PPP\EAP`.

In each of folders look for keys with a backup file (example config backup file  would be ConfigPath).

Delete every original file and rename the backup to the name of the original file (configbackup to config)